# Qt - Replacing a row in the QAbstractItemModel (Tied to a QTableView)

Tags: qt

I had a problem with my QTableView showing an extra empty row whenever I'd change data in a row using :

```
beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
listOfObjects.replace(i, *object);
endInsertRows();
```

I changed it to this, which works but seems very hacky.

```
beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
listOfObjects.replace(i, *object);
endInsertRows();
endRemoveRows();
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Try to emit the `QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged` signal when you change your model data.

Comment: Thanks @hank, I've tried this already and it does not update the view as expected.  Perhaps I'm feeding it incorrect topLeft and bottomRight arguments?  I tried passing a few static int values based on table size and it didn't work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple exmaple.
Let's create a custom table model:

```
class MyModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyModel(int rows, int cols, QObject *parent = 0);

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;

    void updateRow(int row);

private:
    int m_rows, m_cols;
    QMap<int, QMap<int, QString> > updatedItems;
};
```

It has an `updateRow` function that change items text from 'clean' to 'update' and a `QMap` of updated items.

```
MyModel::MyModel(int rows, int cols, QObject *parent) :
    QAbstractTableModel(parent),
    m_rows(rows),
    m_cols(cols)
{
}

int MyModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return m_rows;
}

int MyModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return m_cols;
}

QVariant MyModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    QVariant res;

    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        int row = index.row();
        int col = index.column();

        QString text;

        if (updatedItems.contains(row))
        {
            QMap<int, QString> colData = updatedItems.value(row);
            if (colData.contains(col))
            {
                text = colData.value(col);
            }
        }

        if (text.isEmpty())
        {
            text = QString("clean %1 - %2").arg(row).arg(col);
        }

        res = text;
    }

    return res;
}

void
MyModel::updateRow(int row)
{
    if (updatedItems.contains(row) == false)
    {
        updatedItems[row] = QMap<int, QString>();
    }

    for (int col = 0; col < m_cols; ++col)
    {
        QString text = QString("update %1 - %2").arg(row).arg(col);
        updatedItems[row].insert(col, text);
    }

    QModelIndex index1 = index(row, 0);
    QModelIndex index2 = index(row, m_cols - 1);

    emit dataChanged(index1, index2);
}
```

Check how the `dataChanged` signal is emitted from the last function.

And here is how you can use that model:

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);

    QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton("update");
    view = new QTableView;

    model = new MyModel(4, 5, view);
    view->setModel(model);

    layout->addWidget(btn);
    layout->addWidget(view);

    connect(btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(updateRowData()));

    resize(400, 300);
}

void Widget::updateRowData()
{
    QModelIndex index = view->currentIndex();
    if (index.isValid())
    {
        int row = index.row();

        model->updateRow(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just getting a chance to play with this hank, thanks man.  +1 for now.

Comment: Got the example working, getting a corrupted doubly linked list error, so something isn't right.  I'm assuming model and view are private members of the Widget class, which is all I've done differently with this code.

Comment: Yes, view and model are private members. I don't have any problems with this program, but if you are struggling with it, use a debugger and check what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks again @hank, definitely helped!